# Prevent jupyter console from reading code from jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-console

When on `jupyter` console and I hit the up arrow key, I'd like to go to the previously run line of code on that console. However it will read a previously run cell from a jupyter notebook instead. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: What version of JupyterLab are you using? I'm trying with version 3.2.5 and not seeing that be the case. Even though my console is attached to the notebook, I only see the commands that I've newly run in the console, and then if I continue to go up it then goes back to the ones already run in the notebook **before** I opened the console when I use the up arrow.  Even if I run new code in the notebook with `Show All Kernel Activity` toggled on, it doesn't show that new notebook code when I hit the up arrow in the console. I launched at https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements#readme .

Comment: I'm on 3.3.2 for jupyter lab @Wayne

Comment: Hmmm..even more current. I was hoping you were on an old version. One option would be to wait if any other people have anything to suggest here. If no joy, I'd suggest posting about this over at [the Jupyter Discourse Community Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/). Someone there may have more insight. (If you do post over there, update your question here to reference that so you don't get the same advice in two places and so future people finding this can follow along.